# Sum of rows in ALV table

Tags: abap, alv

How can I sum rows in ABAP using alv report?

sum=gross_weight + net_weight

it creates a new column sum which is the sum of two rows.
I have tried using:

```
wa-fieldname = 'IT_NET_WEIGHT'.
wa-seltext_s = 'Qun'.
wa-ddic_outputlen = '10'.
APPEND wa TO fcat.
wa-fieldname = 'WA_GROSS_WEIGHT'.
wa-seltext_s = 'Qun'.
wa-ddic_outputlen = '10'.
APPEND wa TO fcat.
* Calculate Total for Price
wa-fieldname = 'TOTALS'.
wa-cfieldname = 'WAERK'.
wa-seltext_s = 'Qun'.
wa-do_sum = 'X'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand your internal table with "sum" column. i.e.

```
LOOP AT itab.
   itab-sum = itab-gross_weight + itab-net_weight.
   MODIFY itab.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: that works for only for non alv in ALv i try to declare the sum type p,in the structure but it doesnt regognize that

Answer (score 3):

`DO_SUM` is intended to enable a totals line below the entire table. If you want to have a column that contains the sums, you will have to add this to the data table you're displaying - this is not something the ALV will do for you.

Comment: I am not trying to sum colums,I want a new colum with the sum of the first two for example  gross weight|net_weight|sum   1000 |2000|3000

Comment: I understood that, but that is not something the ALV components will do for you.